# Is there any way to make a Table wider? maybe bootstrap is setting a max-witdh somewhere?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, bootstrap-4

[image]

I can't find how to make this table wider so all columns fit on it, any ideas? Why do i have to add more details here when it's already simple and concise? Sometimes is too hard to add a simple question here.

```
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <tr class="table-primary">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.legacyCode)
        </th>
        <th>
            Laboratorio
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Descripcion)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Excluida)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.sMercado)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Orden)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.legacyCode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Laboratorio.Descripcion)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Descripcion)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Excluida)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.sMercado)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Orden)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href='@Url.Action("Edit", "LineaDeProductos", new { id=item.ID })' class="btn btnModificar btn-sm">Modificar</a>
                <a href='@Url.Action("Details", "LineaDeProductos", new { id=item.ID })' class="btn btnDetalles btn-sm">Detalle</a>
                <a href='@Url.Action("Delete", "LineaDeProductos", new { id=item.ID })' class="btn btnEliminar btn-sm">Eliminar</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

TRY IT LINK: [Example Table](https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1EJ7ZO27B3R)

Comment: What's your outer div? Is its class set to "container"?
Looks like your table is restricted to what it is inside of.
Use Dev Tools and inspect the table and outside of it.

Comment: No outer div, but adding one doesn't make any difference

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your parent container to use `container-fluid`:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <table class="table table-striped">
```

Make sure the parent container is the top most container.

Comment: I did try the container-fluid approach when searching posts to fix this problem, but nothing changes really, the table is not wide enough to hold the content. I'm using MVC 5 bootstrap 4.31

Comment: I just added to my first post an example online  that shows the problem

Comment: You still have a non fluid parent container: `<div class="container body-content">` check your _layout. https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=G1EJGAK2LKMS

Comment: Omg you're right, and the problem was inside my _Layout.cshtml that's way i wasn't seeing it. Thank you! :)